# PHP cURL returning error 505

Tags: php, curl, solr

I'm trying to make cURL (or get_file_contents) get the contents from the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q={!geofilt score=distance sfield=geo pt=20.570529,-100.408635 d=20}&sort=score asc&fq=restaurantes&defType=!edismax&wt=json&indent=true&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score
```

All I get from both methods (cURL and get_file_contents) are HTTP 505 errors. However, if I copy and paste the link to a browser like Firefox it works without problems...

The last thing I tried was forcing cURL to use different HTTP versions with lines like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

without any luck.

My code works for other URL's, like this one:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=restaurantes&defType=edismax&qf=category^20.0+name^10.0+keywords^10.0+address^2.0&wt=json&indent=true&start=0&rows=20&fl=*,score
```

The obvious difference is in characters like {, =, }, ! in the URL. However, why does Firefox work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stupid URL spaces... this fixed it.

```
$qs = str_replace(' ', '+', $qs);
```

Thank you

**Update**: Take a look at PHP's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that with cURL you'll need to fully URL-encode the request parameters (so a space is converted to + etc), and that Firefox is doing this for you behind the scenes.

One way is to pass your arguments to `http_build_query()`.